# How to resolve missing git commit between rebasing?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Okay, so I know this is not the correct way to use git, but I'm helping my workmates in this particular situation.

So let's say I have workmate A and B, and both are committing to the same branch.

One day, A commit to the branch, and sync. When B sync (merge) using Github desktop, B get conflicts.

B resolves the conflicts in local, but he did not make any commit. B continues working and making changes.

And then, A commit again to the same branch, and sync.

B then commit locally. And then B tried to do sync (merge) again using Github desktop.

The problem is, all of B's changes between the first sync and second sync is gone. It's like his commit does not even exist in the `git log`. I checked both in the `git log` and Github desktop commit history, both showed the same thing.

Now he wants to roll back the sync to his commit, but he can't do that because the commit does not exist. The event of the first sync is not even there.

Strangely, the Android Studio version control enlist that there is actually such commit made, with 200 file changes. But when he tried to revert to the commit using the Android Studio, only 1 file reverted, not 200.

How can we fix this situation? How can we revert to a (seemingly) non-existent commit? Does the commit actually exist but orphaned, and there's a way to recall it?

Comment: use reflog to also show orphaned commits. Also this situation seems like a bug in github client. Consider writing a bug report at https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues

Comment: @kutschkem you're right! `git reflog` showed the commit! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git reflog` can show orphaned commits.